# Android DownloadManager won't work with free Web hosting

Tags: android

I try to developp an android application which donwload file from URL, the problem is my file is on my free web hosting and when I download from this link it doesn't work, whereas with another internet link it works. I think that the problem is with my  web hosting and I don't know how to fix it.

If someone can help me.

Thanks for your help.

Here is the code:

```
long enqueue;
            DownloadManager dm;
            try {
                dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://jukebox_2_0.net23.net/files/background_choix_modes_dark.jpg");
                Request request = new Request(uri);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"download_42.jpg");
                enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);

                Log.i("msg", "recu");
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.i("msg",e.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for your problem. This would include your `DownloadManager`-related code, a URL that does not work, and an explanation of your exact symptoms.

Comment: Ok, I edit my question.

Comment: There is nothing obvious about your URL that would seem to cause a problem for `DownloadManager`. The HTTP response seems fairly normal. What exactly does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: When I click on the button the download manager show me failure and Unknown file.

Comment: Check LogCat to see if any interesting messages are being logged. Note that the actual downloading is being done by a separate app, not yours, so you will need to look at all log messages, not just those from your app.

Comment: Yes I've check my logcat, all that I see is the message "reçu" and so there's  no exception with my try catch, is just that it doesn't get the file.

Comment: The message is "Host name may not be null"

Comment: That is really strange. However, this is not a very big file. Unless you specifically want it to show up in the Downloads app, you might just download it yourself. Depending upon what you want to do with it, an image-loading library like Picasso might be a good choice.

Comment: I've fixed my problem, it's because that apache doesn't support underscores, an my hostname is "jukebox_2_0". Thanks you, you really helped me.

Comment: @HuguesBadz it's not Apache that doesn't support `_` - it's the Internet itself... See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names

Comment: Ah ok thank you, the weird things is that my web hosting didn't tell me that it's not support by the internet itself to use underscores.